# SendBird - iOS: Cannot receive camera photo, but can receive stored image

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, sendbird

I'm adding a send picture feature to my app using SendBird.

On `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` I execute this code

```
NSData *imageFileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.5);
NSURL* imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
NSString* imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];

[self.currentChannel sendFileMessageWithBinaryData:imageFileData filename:imageName type:@"image/jpg" size:[imageFileData length] data:nil completionHandler:^(SBDFileMessage * _Nullable fileMessage, SBDError * _Nullable error) {}];
```

This code works well when the imagePicker's sourcetype is: `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

If I send an image with imagePicker which's sourcetype is: `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` then

`- (void)channel:(SBDBaseChannel *)sender didReceiveMessage:(SBDBaseMessage *)message` is never triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, the `info` dictionary from `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` doesn't have an object for `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`. So, the `imagePath` and the `imageName` must be `nil`.

The `sendFileMessageWithBinaryData:filename:type:size:data:completionHandler:` needs `filename` that is not `nil`. Because you generate jpeg data, just use `@"image.jpg"` as the `filename` like this:

```
NSData *imageFileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.5);

[self.currentChannel sendFileMessageWithBinaryData:imageFileData filename:@"image.jpg" type:@"image/jpg" size:[imageFileData length] data:nil completionHandler:^(SBDFileMessage * _Nullable fileMessage, SBDError * _Nullable error) {
}];
```